# MATLAB - Getting an NaN error

Tags: matlab, physics, numerical-methods, astronomy

I'm trying to generate plots of a galactic orbit in a particular potential. My code is given by

```
 function Eulersystem_MNmodel()
 parsec  = 3.08*10^18;
 r_1     = 8.5*1000.0*parsec; % This converts our value of r into cm.
 z_1     = 1.0; 
 theta_1 = 0.0; %Initial Value for Theta.

 U_1     = 100.0*10^5;     %Initial value for U in cm/sec
 V       = 156.972*10^5;   %Proposed value of the radial velocity in cm/sec
 W_1     = 150*10^5.0;

 grav    = 6.6720*10^-8;   %Universal gravitational constant
 amsun   = 1.989*10^33;    %Proposed Angular momentum of the sun
 amg   = 1.5d11*amsun; 
 gm      = grav*amg;       %Note this is constant

 nsteps  = 50000;          %The number of steps
 deltat  = 5.0*10^11;      %Measured in seconds

 angmom  = r_1*V;          %The angular momentum
 angmom2 = angmom^2.0;     %The square of the angular momentum
 E       = -gm/r_1 + U_1*U_1/2 + angmom2/(2.0*r_1*r_1); %Total Energy of the system

 time    = 0.0;

for i=1:nsteps
r_1      = r_1 + deltat*U_1;
U_1      = U_1 + deltat*((-gm*r_1)/((r_1^2.0 + (1+sqrt(z_1^2.0+1))^2.0)^1.50))
z_1      = z_1 + deltat*W_1;
W_1      = W_1 + deltat*(gm*z_1*(1+sqrt(z_1^2.0+1))/(sqrt(z_1^2.0+1))*(r_1^2.0+(1+sqrt(z_1^2.0+1))^2.0)^1.5);


E        = -gm/r_1+U_1/2.0+angmom2/(2.0*r_1*r_1); 
ecc      = (1.0 + (2.0*E*angmom2)/(gm^2.0))^0.5;
time1(i) = time;
time     = time+deltat;
r(i)     = r_1;
z(i)     = z_1;
end

figure()
plot(r,z)
```

I keep getting straight lines, rather than a more interesting curve, which led me to investigate the output of the U_1 function. Upon this investigation I realised that it was consistently outputting NaN "Not a Number". I can't see why I'm getting this however. I've tried replacing sqrt() with ()^0.5, this still yields NaN.

Comment: I think it is .^ you are looking for?

Comment: Where does it generate `NaN`? Generally that only happens upon dividing by zero. The `.^` @GameOfThrows mentioned is taking the element wise power. Simple `^` will take a full matrix power.

Comment: @Adriaan The line U_1      = U_1 + deltat*((-gm*r_1)/((r_1^2.0 + (1+sqrt(z_1^2.0+1))^2.0)^1.50)) generated NaN. As you can see in the code, I haven't included the ; so that I could see what it was outputting

Comment: Replace that line by `U_1 = U_1 + deltat.*((-gm.*r_1)/((r_1.^2.0 + (1+sqrt(z_1.^2.0+1)).^2.0).^1.50))`. Same with the others

Comment: @AnderBiguri I still get NaN if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are operating with rather large numbers. The largest floating point number is something like 1.7e+308. Lager numbers would evaluate to Inf. Similarly, positive numbers smaller than 1.7e-308 would evaluate to zero and cause NaN during division?

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I've done similar things and the code has worked perfectly.